# Divergence of the sum and product of divergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Use the definition of divergence to $\infty$ of a sequence to prove the following results:
>
> (a) if $u_n \to \infty$ and $v_n \to \infty$ then $u_n + v_n \to \infty$ and $u_n v_n \to \infty$;
>
> (b) if $u_n \to \infty$ and $v_n$ is bounded, then $u_n + v_n \to \infty$.

I understand that the definition is that the sequence $u_n \to \infty$ if given any $K>0$, there exists $N$ such that $u_n>K$ whenever $n>N$.

To prove the first bit of part (a), I think the higher of $N$ thresholds of $u_n$ and $v_n$ can be picked to be used as $N$ for $(u+v)_n$. However, I am not sure how to do the other parts.

Comment: Why the vote to close?

Answer (score 1):

- For (a), a "trick:" get rid of $(v_n)_{n\geq 0}$ as soon as possible. Namely, since $(v_n)_{n\geq 0}$ diverges to $\infty$, by definition there exists $N\geq 0$ such that $v_n \geq 1$ for all $n\geq N$.

  Now, for any $n\geq N$, we have $u_n + v_n \geq u_n + 1 > u_n$. You should be able to conclude. Fix $K> 0$: by divergence of $(u_n)_n$, there exists $N'$ such that for all $n\geq N'$, $u_n > K$. For any $n\geq \max(N,N')$, we then have
  $$
  u_n + v_n \geq u_n + 1 > K + 1 > K
  $$
  and you are done.

  For the second, it's similar, with a small little thing to mention on top of that. Fix $K> 0$: by divergence of $(u_n)_n$, there exists $N'$ such that for all $n\geq N'$, $u_n > K$. For any $n\geq \max(N,N')$, we then have
  $$
  u_n v_n \geq u_n > K
  $$
  using first that $u_n > 0$ (as $K>0$) and $v_n \geq 1$, then that $u_n > K$.
- For (b), act similarly: since $(v_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is bounded, there exists $M>0$ such that $-M \leq v_n \leq M$ for every $n\geq 0$. Then, you have that for all $n$, $u_n + v_n \geq u_n - M$.

  Fix any $K>0$, and set $K'\stackrel{\rm def}{=} K+M$. Since $(u_n)_{n\geq 0}$ diverges to $\infty$, there exists $N\geq 0$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $u_n > K'$. But then...